# getting stripe webhook hit on every next button

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to connect and create express account on stripe. I have created the account and the account link. When i am in the stripe onboarding screen and starts filling the information and click on the next button, stripe is sending a webhook to my api. So for every next button stirpe is sending webhook. Is it possible to make it send webhook only at the final submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using hosted Connect onboarding, verification details your users submit are persisted with the API at every stage. As such, an `account.updated` event will be triggered frequently as they complete the onboarding. This is noted [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#return_url):

> No state is passed through this URL. After a user is redirected to your return_url, check the state of the details_submitted parameter on their account by listening to `account.updated` events with a Connect webhook.

You will need to handle the events accordingly to determine the onboarding status of the account.